# Arraryformula with IF

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a very simple formula but don't understand why it does not work?

here is my formula: `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J2:J>P2:P,P2:P,J2:J))`

without array formula : IF(J2>P2,P2,J2))

Anyone can help me understand what am I missing in Arrayformula?

with or without arrayformula my output is same -->[image]

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What's the actual output/error?

Comment: actual output is not an array but a single value is appearing.

Comment: send a link to your sheet. The formula is correct, it should work